# MySQL Workbench not displaying query results

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I query a table in MySQL Workbench, no results are shown, the result section is just blank, no grid or anything. However if I export the data, it is all there. Everything worked fine until a couple days ago.

**Query settings:**

- Max Length = 65536
- Continue on SQL Script Error = true
- "Safe Updates = true
- Leave autocommit mode enabled = true
- Progress status update interval = 500
- Default algorithm for ALTER table = Default
- Default lock for ALTER table = Default
- Limit Rows = true
- Limit Rows Count = 1000
- Max Field Value Length to Display = 256
- Treat BINARY/VARBINARY as nonbinary character string = false
- Confirm Data Changes = True

No queries work, an example would be `SELECT * FROM database.address`

[image]

Comment: what is the query? what are your query options/settings in mysql workbench?

Comment: Added those to the question

Comment: ok do you know if you are linked to the database? on the left there should be schemas... do you see your database with tables inside? can you right click on the table and do SELECT rows limit 1000?

Comment: yeah, they are all there, I can select them and if I export as csv I can view all the data. It just doesn't show up in the result grid...

Comment: ok i may know whats wrong... can you use screencast to take a screenshot? its just a url so you should be able to post that

Comment: is there no action output?

Comment: Apparantly not... didn't notice it was missing too

Comment: hmm.. it might be best to try closing it down restarting and then reopening it

Comment: I was going to say that sometimes people minimize the result set and theres a way to maximize it, but its a little difficult to find...

Comment: IMO it's a bug. The resultset pane is clearly visible, but there's no grid at all. At least the grid header (with the column names) should be visible, even if there's no data in the table. Try resizing the window to see if it is a layout problem. Also, try switching to the form view (second button in the black vertical bar). Results there? And finally, file a bug report for it at http://bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: The values are visible in form view, I tried downgrading to version 5.2 (I was on 6.x) and it still doesn't work...

Comment: I have the same issue, its been since an update happened, if you right click the table name and click on "Select Rows - Limit 1000" it works for me. But I am unable to do any custom queries... this bug is extremely annoying

Comment: Try installing dev release from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: try select * from databasename.tablename

Is your default database is selected. 

try right click of mouse and run select query

Comment: The issue still remains on ubuntu 18.04, using mysql-workbench 8, that's amazing ...

Comment: Restarting Workbench seemed to have fixed it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to ***Ubuntu 14.10***. I found [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-workbench/+bug/1376154) which describes the steps to be followed in order to apply the patch. It takes a while since you have to start all over again: downloading, building, installing... but it worked for me! Sorry I'm not an expert and I can't provide further details.

Here are the steps described in the link above:

> If you want to patch and build mysql-workbench yourself, get the source from for 6.2.3. From the directory you downloaded it to, do:
>
> wget 'http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.2.3-src.tar.gz'
>
> tar xvf mysql-workbench-community-6.2.3-src.tar.gz && cd mysql-workbench-community-6.2.3-src
>
> wget -O patch-glib.diff 'http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=21874&bug_id=74147'
>
> patch -p0 < patch-glib.diff
>
> sudo apt-get build-dep mysql-workbench
>
> sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
>
> cd build
>
> cmake .. -DBUILD_CONFIG=mysql_release
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Just don't do it before leaving your office. The `make` step take something like half an hour on an Core i7.

Comment: I have finished my build but I don't know what file will allow me to launch the fixed app :/

Comment: @LaurentG If you already had MySQL Workbench installed by aptitude then the last command would simply overwrite it with the patched version. Otherwise, you should find your binary at /usr/bin/mysql-workbench or /usr/local/bin/mysql-workbench.

Comment: I had to make the process a second time to make it work, but I'm now an  happy man :)

Comment: I can also confirm JuanN's workflow. I just finished applying the patch and I now have a working MySQL Workbench on **Ubuntu 14.10**.

Comment: I can confirm the workflow for openSUSE 13.2. / Workbench 6.2.3

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is shaking my faith a little...between this and problems with ssh connections to database servers.  Hopefully we can get these things resolved in the repos soon so people can upgrade to 14.10 with confidence!

Comment: I've completed every step successfully, but it didn't work for me. You can see my error output here http://pastebin.com/FStDL9Rn

Comment: (Depending on the shell, I suppose) You must enclose the url between quotes :
wget -O patch-glib.diff 'http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=21874&bug_id=74147'
I edited the answer to include them, but it must be "peer-reviewed"

Comment: Thanks dude, you save me after 1 month of chaos. ++1

Comment: I had the same prob and after about half an hour its done :)

Answer (score 107):

This is a known bug: [link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72897).
Upcoming release 6.2.2 fixes this for OS X (Unfortunately, Linux version is still [broken](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72203)).

At least on my computer it's not dissapeared, just folded, and it's edge is almost merged with the edge of 'Action Output' block. When you move your mouse to that edge, the cursor starts looking like a dash with two arrows. Slowly move it couple of pixels higher until you catch the small 1px area where the cursor changes to a dash with a single arrow. Then catch it and pull : )

I've made a couple of photos to illustrate this.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

Comment: Actually, no this does not resolve the OP's question.  Yes, it does resolve the Results pain hiding (I had that issue on OSX, and yes you can re-drag it into view as it is shown in this answer).  BUT, that is not the problem the OP lists.  Her problem (and MINE!) is that the Results pane is shown, as you can see in the screenshot (therefore, it isn't the problem).  The problem seems to be a FONT or scaling issue on the pane itself.  I am running Debian linux and with the i3wm, I see what the OP sees - a results panel that is blank; but, we can EXPORT just fine.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem :) How can we avoid this?

Comment: This was my problem on Ubuntu 14.04. Glad I didn't go through building from source as suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: Can not see Step 1, Step 2 or Step 3!

Comment: Didn't work for me at first.  However, after dragging my "Action Output" pane all the way down (and out of view), I was able to grab the "single arrow" and pull it up.  Then I was able to go down again and grab the "double arrow" to get my "Action Output" back.

Comment: Still has the same problem

Comment: I was able to resolve this by quitting MySQL Workbench and opening it again.

Comment: unbelievable this is still broken 7 years later

Answer (score 64):

New to MySql myself and found this is happening on Windows as well.  Goto Query > Explain Current Statement > click on the Results Grid icon on the far right of the Visual Explain window that shows by default.  You may have to toggle through the up down arrow icons to see it.

Comment: thanks! 
I wasted more than half an hour trying to recover the results grid
this worked for me!

Comment: Wow, what an awful GUI.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I was initially very excited for this, but it turns out it's a very temporary fix. :(  I can't scroll through the results and if I execute the query again, I go back to losing my results.  Guess I'll need to continue to restart Workbench every time this happens (OFTEN!).

Comment: prefect solution.

Comment: Windows 10 user here. The result grid disappeared after I rerun my query. I had to close the app to make it reappear.

Comment: In Windows 8, the same happened as @PeterSzalay mentioned. After following the recommeded solution, I had to restart MySQL and then things were back to normal.

Comment: Also this works with queries but doesn't work with procedures. So for a procedure you need to extract your query to be able to check the results. Very frustrating.

Comment: Can't believe I still have to use this trick to fix mine after macos sonoma beta upgrade in 2023! MySql workbench hide the query result in a weird way that I have to resize different panes to get it display properly every time I open a new query window. I updated the most recent version 8.0.34, same thing. Thanks to this trick, it seems fixed

Answer (score 12):

It was really frustrating as it was still happening in the workbench version 6.3.10 (for mac) available in the mysql official site ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)).
I got it resolved by first collapsing the bottom panel (check the top right in the attached image (termed as collapse button)) and then pulling up the empty region from the bottom.
Now if I again click on collapse button this time result grid is visible along with the action grid.

[image: collapse the bottom panel]

[image: visible result grid]

Comment: Yes, its still happening. I am so frustrated. The result page is always blank. Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: Actually grid is behind bottom panel hence you are not able to pull it up using mouse, the solution is to collapse the bottom panel and then try to drag grid upwords using mouse. Now again click on bottom panel icon (marked in the image check top right). Now you should be able to see the grid.

Answer (score 6):

The problem, as it is described, corresponds exactly to the bug [MySQL Bugs: #74147: empty grid result, incompatibiliity with libglib_2.42](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74147)

The good news is it's almost closed.

A patch is available since today.

EDIT :
In Debian Jessie (testing), the problem is solved with the package mysql-workbench 6.2.3+dfsg-6 available since today.

Comment: Uninstalling ubuntu version & installing debian's mysql-workbench 6.2.3+dfsg-6 and data packages worked on Ubuntu 14.10. Direct links so you save time - Data: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mysql-workbench-data and Workbench: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mysql-workbench (scroll to the bottom to search for your architecture)

Comment: FYI, it seems lots of people are still having issues now that 6.2.4 was released with the so-called patch.  It did not fix it on my Debian 7 Testing install (built from source). Going to attempt the apt package dep build above in another answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Update manually from [mysql website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

Here's a solution for Ubuntu 15.04 users running Mysql Workbench 6.2.3.

I was able to resolve the issue of missing results in the Mysql workbench by just upgrading mysql-workbench to version 6.3.3 from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/. You will need to download the one marked for Ubuntu 14.10. An install via Ubuntu software center resolved the issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

This was still happening to me on version 6.3.9 on OSX. I downloaded 6.1.7 again to actually see the result grid again.

What a pain in the butt!

Comment: I had 6.3.9 and just upgraded to High Sierra. The upgrade busted everything up. There is an update to 6.3.10 and it seems to fix the interface.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest fix for me to see the Result Grid again was to click on `Explain Command`

[[image]

After that `Execution Plan` is going to be shown and on the right side you can click on `Result Grid`

[image]

Comment: saved the day, this should be the answer.

Comment: Thanks!This so frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using MySqlWorkbench 6.3.9 on macOS and has this problem. I removed the app and installed 6.3.10 which solves the problem.

Comment: Same problem on osx 10.13.2, resolved with workbench 6.3.10

Comment: Awesomely, MySQL Workbench version 6.3.4.0 on macOS tells you that you are using the most up to date version when you have it check for updates. Manually updating to 6.3.10 from Oracle's website fixed the problem for me, although my problem is the one mentioned in the answer with screenshots from macOS, not the problem that the OP had.

Comment: Yes, previous MySQL Workbench version wrongly reported that it was up to date

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to compile it yourself you can go to:

```
Applications→Ubuntu Software Center→Edit→Software Sources→Updates
```

there you can check hardy-proposed is ticked(for 14.10 will be utopic-proposed)
[image: demo image]

[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) 
then simply go to terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

As a note, you will get other updates to, witch may not be stable!!!

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I tried both mysql-workbench and mysql-workbench-community

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench 6.3.4 fixes this issue. Custom builds are not needed anymore.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Not for me, perhaps it has something to do with Ubuntu itself?

Answer (score 1):

The result set wasn't showing for me either.  I was able to make it appear by hiding the output area and running a simple select statement.  Then I "show"ed the output area again and had what I was looking for -- both the result set and the output area

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by doing the following...

1. Go to the MySQL website for Workbench: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
2. Once there scroll to the bottom of the page and click on the tab that says "Development Releases"
3. Select your platform, download & install

You will likely want to uninstall any workbench packages already installed. GL!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Using MySQL 6.1 Workbench.

After a while (2 mins), it just crashed.  Reported bug, saved files and reopened.  It works now.

I guess I would suggest if that happens again, to immediately save the open scripts, close MySQL and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the TAB. From the tab's title I assume you first made a right click > "Select Rows - Limit 1000". But when you enter a different query in the opening tab, it won't show anything any more... Don't know why. Open a new tab for manual queries, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated macOS to **10.13.4** and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for almost an hour, tried everything, restarted Workbench, upgraded Workbench, used the "explain query" trick, but nothing worked.

The explanation for the result grid not showing anymore was actually very stupid: there was a `INSERT INTO mytable` few lines above the `SELECT` query. I share it anyway because it might help some other people.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I think it is a problem "screen size" related. Some Workbench versions present this problem, accordingly the numerous other answers.

However, I'd solved this by simply lowering the monitor resolution and the Result Grid has back to be draggable with the mouse pointer (very like the Thaumant answer already indicated).

I've taken these photos to illustrate what I'm saying.

- At 1440x900 the Result Grid draggable selector are not being showed...

[image]

- Now, in 800x600 resolution (with 125% of scale) the Result Grid has back to be draggable !

[image: Now I finnaly can pop up my grid again !]

Works too with greater resolutions along with bit of scaling*