# mysql workbench does not show results for 6.3 and mac

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

riddle me this....  oracle are you listing?

[image]

Wow..why are results not being shown?

Yes I tried to use the mouse cursor to see if collapsed

Yes I have the view output visible

Mac OS High Sierra

Workbench 6.3

It really seems that Oracle really does not care about mysql

Should be soooo simple

1) run query

2) view table

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739198/mysql-workbench-not-displaying-query-results

Comment: that post was over 3 years ago....different versions and different OS

Comment: It worked for me on Sierra a couple of months ago. I had the same issue and that's the post that helped me

Comment: I'm having the exactly same issue. Also macOS.

Comment: A new release is on its way out which fixes this problem (6.3.10). Should hit public very soon.

Comment: I can confirm that 6.3.10 for mac OS resolved the issue.  Thanks mysql!

Answer (score 2):

Updating to 6.3.10 will solve the problem. My mac version is 10.13.1 High Sierra, faced the same problem.